# SASS with Angular 4 Error

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

So i've been messing around with my first Angular(4) app, using the Angular CLI. I was just about to start dealing with the design of the app and wanted to learn/use SASS.

I've read some things on how to use it so i did the following:
- installed ruby
- installed sass through ruby
- 'ng set defaults.styleExt scss'
- created a main.scss file and updated this on angular-cli.json:

```
"styles": [
        "styles/main.scss"
      ],
```

If edit something on main.scss nothing happens, the styles are not being applied and if i try to delete the old 'styles.css' file i get an error and i access the app.

Comment: Does this help?  https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/wiki/How-to-include-SCSS-in-components

Comment: What errors are you getting

Comment: @Skeptor i'm getting this when i try to ng serve:

ERROR in multi ./src/styles/main.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\nixto\Desktop\ubichallenge\ubic                                                                                              hallenge\src\styles\main.scss' in 'C:\Users\nixto\Desktop\ubichallenge\ubichalle                                                                                              nge\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs'
 @ multi ./src/styles/main.scss

Comment: Yess!! I did that and it just compiled without errors and my styles.scss is now working. Thank you so much! @EamonnMcEvoy